# Loading Images from URLRequest using Alamofire responseImage IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, alamofire, alamofireimage

Good day.

I am currently using Alamofire version 4.5 and xcode version 9.3. I am trying to load images from URLrequest with custom headers to a collection view with image from a fileserver using this code

```
var imageRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "myurl here ")!)
imageRequest.addValue(MyVariables.accountToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "accountToken")

imageRequest.addValue("header value 1", forHTTPHeaderField: "header field 1")

imageRequest.addValue("header value 2", forHTTPHeaderField: "header field 2")

imageRequest.addValue(imageurl from fileserver, forHTTPHeaderField: "file")
```

After adding headers to the urlrequest I use this alamofire responseimage to set value to the image

```
            Alamofire.request(imageURLRequest).responseImage { response in
            if let image = response.result.value {
                self.count += 1
                print("image  \(self.count )", image)
            } else {
                print("unable to load   \(self.count)")
            }
        }
```

The problem I am encountering is that not all images are loading at once eventhough I have already looped in the alamofire request with the number of urlrequests I have. Another thing, when I scroll the collectionview the photos I have loaded from the alamofire call jumbles in order not following the indexpath.row. Moreover, I have also tried to append the image response from my alamofire response image and set it to 
`cell.imageView.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]`

but it goes out of bounds. When I log the the alamofire imageresponse it only loads until index 7. I have tried different approach like appending the urlrequest to array and loading it to collection view cell via

```
cell.imageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: imageURLRquest)
```

but it only loads the first item in the image array. Sorry for the long question as I have tried most of the solutions I have found so far but it doesnt fix the problem I have right now. Please provide suggestions to fix this. Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

Here is the code for the datasource from alamofire request. It returns 10 urlrequest that is being appended to the array

```
var imageRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "myurl here ")!)
imageRequest.addValue(MyVariables.accountToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "accountToken")

imageRequest.addValue("header value 1", forHTTPHeaderField: "header field 1")

imageRequest.addValue("header value 2", forHTTPHeaderField: "header field 2")

imageRequest.addValue(imageurl from fileserver, forHTTPHeaderField: "file")

self.imageArray.append(imageRequest)
```

This is for the cellForItemAt

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BooksCell", for: indexPath) as! LibraryCollectionViewCell

        cell.imageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: self.imageArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.bookName.text = self.booksObject[indexPath.row].object(forKey: "title") as! String
        cell.cosmosRatingView.rating = self.booksObject[indexPath.row].object(forKey: "rating") as! Double

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: where is  image array , when you use this `cell.imageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: imageURLRquest)` , what is `datasource` for your `CollectionView`

Comment: I am setting my image at cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath. imageArray is an array of URLRequest from an alamofire call with the custom headers added to the urlrequest

Comment: share your cell for row code

Comment: `cell.imageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: self.imageArray[indexPath.row])`

Comment: with this the index goes out of bounds

Comment: so you have an error please share full code of your cell and data source

Comment: @Abdelahad Darwish Please see the updated code. Thank you

Comment: `self.booksObject`  is your data source or  `self.imageArray`  which one in `numberofitemspersection`

Comment: `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       
        return self.booksObject.count
    }`

Comment: @Je. you should share the complete code of this ViewController/class, After seeing the shared code it looks everything is good. OR verify that all requests are getting triggered and returns success (some of the request might be failing)

Comment: Hi @Satish. I am loading images from urlrequest. Are there any other way to load images in tableviews or collectionviews from urlrequests with custom headers? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day. I have already found the solution for this. You would need to reset the value of the imageView to nil at cellForItemAt then assign it to the indexPath.row

```
 if let image = self.bookImages[indexPath.row]  {
        cell.imageView.image = image
    } else {
        Alamofire.request(imageURLRequest).responseImage { response in
            if let image = response.result.value {
                cell.imageView.image = image
                self.bookImages[indexPath.row]  = image
            } else {
                cell.imageView.image = placeholderImage
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for all your help. Hope this also helps someone who encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have error  at `self.imageArray[indexPath.row]` will crash with `index goes out of bounds`  because number of items in cell will be equal to `self.booksObject.count-1`  what if   self.booksObject is greater than image array ?!

so you have to make sure that `self.imageArray.count  =   self.booksObject.count`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
return self.booksObject.count 
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BooksCell", for: indexPath) as! LibraryCollectionViewCell

        cell.imageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: self.imageArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.bookName.text = self.booksObject[indexPath.row].object(forKey: "title") as! String
        cell.cosmosRatingView.rating = self.booksObject[indexPath.row].object(forKey: "rating") as! Double

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: right. The thing is I would need to have self.booksObject.count as the numberOfItemsInSection because I am expecting to receive 10 urlrequests. The problem is that whenever I use `Alamofire.request(imageURLRequest).responseImage { response in
            if let image = response.result.value {
                self.count += 1
                print("image  \(self.count )", image)
            } else {
                print("unable to load   \(self.count)")
            }
        }` it does not return 10 alamofire calls for all the 10 urlrequests

Comment: Are you able to give me other options on how to load images from urlrequest with custom headers? Thank you